# Fetch the top 5 records from 2 tables each using single query

Tags: mysql

I want to fetch the top 10 records from 2 tables which have `id` as reference id using single query.

For example, I have `student` and `Student_details` tables.

Now I want to fetch top 5 records of `student` table and top 5 records of `Student_details` table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you want to have the results from both tables combined in 1 result set?

If so, then use

```
SELECT student.*, student_details.*
FROM student, student_details
WHERE student.id = student_details.student_id
ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;
SELECT * FROM student_details ORDER BY id ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM STUDENTS ORDER BY ID LIMIT 5
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE ... ORDER BY ... DESC/ASC LIMIT 5;
```

Do it twice.

Comment: Thanks but I want in single query

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible! You could create a temporary table and somehow try to match the fields of one table to match the field of the other if they both have almost the same number of fields - only then you could use a single query to get the top 5 results of both tables using one query. But even then this would lead to more than a single query (because you had to create the temp table first).

The best you can do is to use two queries:

```
SELECT * FROM student ORDER BY student.id LIMIT 5;
SELECT * FROM student_details ORDER BY student_details.id LIMIT 5;
```

Comment: I want top 5 records from student table and top 5 records from Student_details table using single query.